# How do you center a netlify badge on a README.md?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I'm having a hard time centering my netlify badge on my readme, using a `p` tag with an align of "center" doesn't seem to work. What would be the proper way?

This is the code I have so far:

```markdown
<p align="center">
    
[![Netlify Status](https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/badges/bc438b2e-9f12-4bbe-987e-d36fcef20a2f/deploy-status)](https://app.netlify.com/sites/darienmiller/deploys)
</p>
```

[image: Netlify Status]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) doesn't allow you to tweak alignment directly

Use an img tag instead of markdown.

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/badges/bc438b2e-9f12-4bbe-987e-d36fcef20a2f/deploy-status">
</p>
```

If you review the generated HTML by the Markdown method, your paragraph tag is terminated before the image, preventing the centering from being applied.